# GET (JSON) is removing leading zeros

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to use jQuery to pass "0002" to a WebMethod. But the leading zeros are truncated :(

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "CallNote.aspx/GetStoreRegion?storeCode=0002",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  //dataType: "json", - Brad is right I don't need this line
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response.d);
  }
});
```

In CallNote.aspx.cs:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string GetStoreRegion(string storeCode)
{
  // Problem: Here storeCode becomes "2", not "0002"
  return myService.GetStoreRegion(storeCode);
}
```

How do you pass the string "0002" correctly?

Comment: Not sure I understand. All query parameters are strings and nothing in your code shows any automatic conversion to a numeric type. In fact, nothing in your code shows a reason for `x0002` to not work either as your data type is `string`

Comment: Not sure what your question has to do with JSON, since there is no JSON in the request and your problem is only on parsing request data....

Comment: It has to do something with the server side code not javascript. Show us what you have on your server.

Comment: Brad, you're right. I copied an existing POST and changed it to GET. I may not need JSON?

Comment: Pamio, I already put up the WebMethod in the question. I think that's all the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you're telling ASP.NET that you'r passing the data as JSON. So, ASP.NET believes you. So, what would happen if you said `var x = {storeCode: 0002};`. Well, it would get turned into `2` because you aren't surrounding it in quotes. So you need to do the same thing for your parameter. If you want a string you'd do: `var x = {storeCode: '0002'};` so in your case you want:

`url: "CallNote.aspx/GetStoreRegion?storeCode='0002'",`

Comment: You are a genious!! Thank you!

Comment: P.S., you could also just use: PageMethods.GetStoreRegion('0002')